# how to know which fonts are being used in PDF?

Tags: windows-xp, pdf

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to know which fonts are used in selected part of a PDF document](https://superuser.com/questions/117443/how-to-know-which-fonts-are-used-in-selected-part-of-a-pdf-document)

how to know which fonts are being used in PDF?

Comment: Duplicate: http://superuser.com/questions/117443/how-to-know-which-fonts-are-used-in-selected-part-of-a-pdf-document

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Adobe Reader (I'm using version 9 currently, but I gather it is the same on the other versions) go to File/Properties/Fonts. It should show you a list of used fonts.

Comment: but it showing one font multiple times

Comment: @Jitendra vyas - although I'm not an expert on fonts, that depends on how the font is structured. ... tell me, why do you need this ?