# Finding font size used in pdf

Tags: pdf, fonts

I want to find the font types and sizes used in a pdf document. I managed to find the font types with `strings foo.pdf | grep FontName` as described in the link below. Is there a similar trick that will allow me to find the font sizes?

[How to know which fonts are used in selected part of a PDF document](https://superuser.com/questions/117443/how-to-know-which-fonts-are-used-in-selected-part-of-a-pdf-document)

Comment: Open the PDF in Firefox, right click on the content and select "Inspect (Q). Under the "Inspector" tab, do a search for the string of interest. When you find it, look to the right for info on font size...you may need to move the cursor up a line or so in the left window...

Answer (score 0):

The question you linked already has an accepted answer providing the data you need.

I think you're looking for Linux alternative for the functionality the program `PDF-XChange Viewer` provides.

[Wikipedia says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PDF-XChange_Viewer) the program can be run using Wine.