# How to find out where a specific font is used in an uneditable PDF document with Adobe Acrobat Pro DC?

Tags: pdf, fonts, adobe-acrobat, acrobat-pro-dc

I would like to know where a specific font is used in a PDF document with Adobe Acrobat Pro DC. I understand that there is [another similar question](https://superuser.com/questions/62562), but this one deals with how to do this in older versions of the software.

- My document is uneditable since it has been digitally signed by a third party, and I cannot clear the digital signature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do this myself. The most challenging problem was that I didn't know how to create preflight profiles in Acrobat Pro DC. [The first answer](https://superuser.com/a/486448/1218738) of that question was the most helpful, except that it was about Acrobat 9 Pro, which had a different method of creating preflight profiles. I hope this answer will be helpful for those who are using Acrobat DC Pro.

#### Creating Preflight Profiles

[This](https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/using/preflight-profiles-acrobat-pro.html#view_profiles) Adobe user guide shows how to create preflight profiles. The reason I chose not to link to the specific section that actually talks about how to create them is that you need to know how to get to the Preflight Profile dialog box before you can do anything else.

#### Adding Checks

The most important component of a preflight profile are its checks. You can simply follow the instructions labeled in the linked answer. Hope this helps!